# Android SDK avd emulator kernel does not include netfilter/iptables

Tags: android, netfilter

1. Where can I find the kernel including netfilter/iptables?
2. Can I assume most market phones has netfilter included within their kernels?

Answer (score 0):

Android kernel includes iptables binary from Android 2.2 and upwards.You need to root your phone in order to access it. Or else flash your ROM to Cyanogenmod ROM.